# jQuery - slideDown method, it goes down but will not go back up

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

I have sourced this working fiddle where a div will slide up and down when a div is clicked. It works great in the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/dRpWv/1/

I have now applied the same code to my website, the div will slide down but clicking the div again does nothing.

```
$( ".widget_head" ).click(function() {
$( ".widget_body" ).slideDown( "fast", function() {
// Animation complete.
})
})
```

.widget_head can be found by clicking the "Cars by type" tab on the left side of the page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) has been removed from  version 1.9 and you are using `jQuery v1.10.2` in your site.

It works in fiddle as ---> fiddle has `jQuery v1.8.3` .

---

Use this code

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/8KYK9/)</kbd>

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button").click(function () {
        var txt = ($(this).text() == 'Hide Content') ? 'show Content' : 'Hide Content';
        $(this).text(txt);
        $("#hidden_content").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/